# I want to know how sms gateway response work?How do I get the delivery report form sms APi?

Tags: php, sms

MY SMS CODE: I have purchased the sms gate from third party.I am having some issue with that when I integrate in my website. I have listed my issue.can anyone guide me what I have to do further?Read my question?

```
<?php
$ID = 'xxxxxx'; 
$Pwd = 'xxxxx'; 
$PhNo = '1234567890,123456789'; 
$Text = 'welcome to US';
$url="http://t.dialmenow.info/sendsms.jsp?user=$ID&password=$Pwd&mobiles=$PhNo&sms=$Text&senderid =";
//echo $url;
$ret = file($url);
//echo $ret;
 echo $ret[9];
?>

**I have problem with my message and delivery report.**
1.If you see the $Text variable $Text=welcome to US if I give space after first word the message is not coming to my mobile.
2.In api documentation they have given how to check delivery status. Here is the api delivery status code.they have given sample code. I want to know how to write the sample delivery status code for above php code.

http://t.dialmenow.info/getDLR.jsp?userid=username&password=password&messageid=1,2&externalid=1,2  &drquantity=X&fromdate=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss&todate=yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss&redownload=yes&responcetype=xml

Explanation:
messageid=>When you send a message you will get an unique message id from API and you have to use this      
messageid=>for getting the deliver status for that message.     
externalid=>unique sms serial no which you will get in response.        
Drquantity=>it means how many delivery status you want from Dialmenow application
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your message using the below 
$msg = urlencode($Text)

Havent used file() but you could try implementing via cURL. Pls ensure that [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in installed in the server where the code will be executed.

```
$ID = 'xxxxxx';
$Pwd = 'xxxxx';
$PhNo = '1234567890,123456789';
$Text = 'welcome to US';
$msg=urlencode($Text);
$url="http://t.dialmenow.info/sendsms.jsp?user=$ID&password=$Pwd&mobiles=$PhNo&sms=$msg&senderid=";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```